# Undefined errors list in http response

Tags: angular, typescript, http, error-handling

I am trying to make a sign up component with Angular but when im trying to get the returned errors it seems that `error.error` is undefined and I don't find why.

```
register(username: string, email: string, password: string): string[] {
    this.http.post(`${env.apiUrl}/auth/register`, { username: username, email: email, password: password }, { headers: headers, observe: 'response' })
      .subscribe({
        next: (res: any) => {

        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.log(error.error);
          return error.error;
        }
    })
    return [];
  }
```

[image: Response HTTP]

**[image: strong text]**

Comment: Can you please `console.log(error)` and share the result?

Comment: I do have added it now